# UITableView Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

When using Xcode's Analyze tool I receive the following memory leak warning for this `UITableView` allocation -

```
Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
```

```
self.contentTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];  
self.contentTableView.delegate = self;
self.contentTableView.dataSource = self;
self.contentTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.contentTableView.backgroundColor = [AppDelegate appMainColor];
self.contentTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.contentTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
[self.view addSubview:self.contentTableView];
```

Anyone has encountered this warning? solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiousity, are you writing this code yourself, or is it imported from external libraries? If you are writing it yourself, why not use [ARC](http://maniacdev.com/ios-5-sdk-tutorial-and-guide/arc-automatic-reference-counting/)? This helps with garbage collection easily and quite efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, but my app's deployment target is lower than 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this a guess. I havent worked on legacy targets for a long while. I have been deploying on the later targets. But you can either use the `autorelease` or manually release the `UITableView`. Something like this may work,

```
self.contentTableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
```

OR if you are using a property, then release inside your `dealloc` method,

```
[tableView release];
```

**NOTE**: I havent worked with non-ARC environment for a long time and my syntax might (most likely) be wrong and you have to work out syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since ARC is not an option for you, you need to follow the ownership rules in code. You have created an object using `alloc`, so you must make sure it gets a `release` later. An easy way to do this is to send it `autorelease` when you instantiate it and assign it to your property, like:

```
self.contentTableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
```